# INSERT SELECT not minimally logged

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following query is minimally logged:

```
INSERT [HIST_DB].[DBO].[HIST_TABLE] WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT [Hash] FROM [DSA_DB].[DBO].[DSA_TABLE] SRC
```

Locks (sp_whoisactive):

```
<Database name="DSA_DB">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="DSA_TABLE" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IS" request_status="GRANT" request_count="9" />
        <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK_DSA_TABLE" request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="5" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>
<Database name="HIST_DB">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="(null)">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="DATABASE.BULKOP_BACKUP_DB" request_mode="NULL" request_status="GRANT" request_count="9" />
        <Lock resource_type="DATABASE.BULKOP_BACKUP_LOG" request_mode="NULL" request_status="GRANT" request_count="9" />
        <Lock resource_type="DATABASE.ENCRYPTION_SCAN" request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="9" />
        <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
    <Object name="HIST_TABLE" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="ALLOCATION_UNIT.BULK_OPERATION_PAGE" request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="9" />
        <Lock resource_type="HOBT.BULK_OPERATION" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="9" />
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="BU" request_status="GRANT" request_count="8" />
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>
```

---

The following query is **not** minimally logged:

```
INSERT [HIST_DB].[DBO].[HIST_TABLE] WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT [Hash] FROM [DSA_DB].[DBO].[DSA_TABLE] SRC
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT [Hash] FROM [HIST_DB].[DBO].[HIST_TABLE] TGT WITH
    WHERE TGT.[Hash] = SRC.[Hash]
)
```

Locks (sp_whoisactive):

```
<Database name="DSA_DB">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="DSA_TABLE" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IS" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
        <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK_DSA_TABLE" request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>
<Database name="HIST_DB">
  <Locks>
    <Lock request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
  </Locks>
  <Objects>
    <Object name="(null)">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="DATABASE.BULKOP_BACKUP_DB" request_mode="NULL" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
        <Lock resource_type="DATABASE.BULKOP_BACKUP_LOG" request_mode="NULL" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
    <Object name="HIST_TABLE" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</Database>
```

How come that the second query is not minimally logged?

Comment: I'm going through the list on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422(v=sql.105).aspx and one that jumps out to me is that the behavior changes depending on whether the table has a clustered index and is empty or not (minimal logging possible on an empty target table, not possible on a table that has data). I'm referring specifically to "If the table has a clustered index and is empty, both data and index pages are minimally logged. In contrast, if a table has a clustered index and is non-empty, data pages and index pages are both fully logged regardless of the recovery model."

Comment: @BenThul, The target table is empty in both tests.

Comment: Try using the TABLOCK hint also for the HIST_TABLE in the subquery.